# Java Maven - Error: No compiler is provided

Tags: java, maven

I try use IntelliJ and Maven, but I have a problem. I have JDK: corretto-11.0.21 .

```
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.9.2 (c9616018c7a021c1c39be70fb2843d6f5f9b8a1c)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3
Java version: 1.8.0_211, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_211
Default locale: pl_PL, platform encoding: Cp1250
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

When I use command: mvn clean package

```
[WARNING] Plugin validation issues were detected in 2 plugin(s)
[WARNING]
[WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1
[WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For more or less details, use 'maven.plugin.validation' property with one of the values (case insensitive): [BRIEF, DEFAULT, VERBOSE]
[WARNING]
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project MavenTest3: Compilation failure        
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

I'm new to Java. I keep trying to solve the problem, but to no avail.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You are saying you have Jdk-11, but it seems Java8 is on your PATH `Java version: 1.8.0_211`. Define environment JAVA_HOME and PATH to the jdk-11 locations.
https://www.baeldung.com/java-home-on-windows-7-8-10-mac-os-x-linux

Comment: Yes, I have `JRE 1.8.0_211` on my system, because Cisco ASDM software requires this version. Due to Cisco, I cannot update the Java JRE version.  However, I installed `JDK-11` via InteliiJ and I select them when creating a new project. I think two versions of Java JRE in the system are not allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already posted everything to figure out:

As Maven already stated in the error output:

```
Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

Plus the above output also shows

```
Java version: 1.8.0_211, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_211`.
```

So just install a proper JDK and set JAVA_HOME correctly before invoking Maven again.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a JRE instead of a JDK. Set the environment variable JAVA_HOME to to the path to an actual JDK. A JRE doesn't include the compiler.